# Find one sided limit to show equivalence

Tags: limits, logarithms, exponential-function, mathematical-modeling

I'm working on a problem that looks at growth models and I'm trying to show that the equation,

$\frac{dN}{dt}$ = $aN^{\gamma}$ - $bN^{\gamma}$($\frac{N^{\gamma -1} - 1}{1 - \gamma}$)

is equivalent to the equation

$\frac{dN}{dt}$ = $-bNlog(\frac{N}{K})$

for the limit $\gamma \to 1^{-}$

---

The first equation is a rewritten version of the Bertalanffy equation and the second is the Gompertz equation. The Gompertz equation would be a special case of the Berttananffy equation. We would want to find $K$ in terms of $a$ and $b$ aswell.

Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: $\lim_{\gamma \to 1^-} \frac{N^{\gamma-1}-1}{\gamma-1}$ is the derivative of $f(\gamma) := N^{\gamma-1}$ at $\gamma=1$, which is $f'(1) = \log N$.
So $\lim_{\gamma \to 1^-} (aN^\gamma - bN^\gamma \frac{N^{\gamma-1}-1}{1-\gamma}) = aN+bN \log N$.

Comment: The derivative of $f(\gamma) = N^{\gamma-1}$ is $\frac{d}{d\gamma}f(\gamma) = N^{\gamma-1}\ln(N)$. I don't see how your first statement is true. @angryavian

Comment: By the definition of a derivative, $f'(0) = \lim_{\gamma \to 1} \frac{f(\gamma)-f(1)}{\gamma-1}$. Note that $f(1)=1$. @Paichu

Comment: I don't follow still. Wouldn't it be $f'(1) = \lim_{\gamma\rightarrow 1} \frac{f(\gamma) - f(1)}{\gamma -1}$? @angryavian

Comment: @Paichu Sorry, yes I meant $f'(1)$.